# how do I change my header background color?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the header background red along the navigation menu. however, my html/css does not work as intended. can you tell me what I did wrong? I though that header selector is the container of my topnav section. not sure why changing background-color through header style doesn't do anything. if I put the bakcground-color under the .topnav a, there will be a gap between the floating elements

```
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #4c8b41;


}

header {
    background-color: red;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f8f8f8;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: black;

}

#topnav-right {
    float: right;    
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#"><h2>Home</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></h2></a>
            <div id="topnav-right">
                <a href="#"><h2>Log In</h2></a>
                <a href="#"><h2>Sign Up</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         margin: 0;
         background-color: #4c8b41;
         }
         
         header {
           background-color: red;
           height:100px;
         }
         
         .topnav a {
         float: left;
         color: #f8f8f8;
         text-align: center;
         text-decoration: none;
         padding: 10px 10px;
         }
         
         .topnav a:hover {
         background-color: black;
         }
         
         #topnav-right {
         float: right;    
         }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#">
               <h2>Home</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
               <h2><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></h2>
            </a>
            <div id="topnav-right">
               <a href="#">
                  <h2>Log In</h2>
               </a>
               <a href="#">
                  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey it works!!!! can you tell me why setting the height property fixes it? what is the default value?

Comment: you define div in header tag and if you want to set background color on header tag than you have to set height for header based on inside content
but if you want to set background color on div than you don't need to define height

Answer (score 3):

The following rule will only work on elements that have `class="header"`, not the header element. Instead use:

```
header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

CSS selectors use the following syntax:

```
tag
{
  ...
}
.class
{
  ...
}
#id
{
  ...
}
```

Note that the tag has nothing prefacing it, which is what you want to do in the case of the header.

**UPDATE**: The problem also lies in that the `header` element has no height, so the background is not visible. Note that this is because of the floated anchor tags within the `.topnav` element. Note the CSS updates to the .topnav:after, which provide a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix).

```html
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #4c8b41;
    }
    
    header {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .topnav:after {
      clear: both;
      display: block;
      content: "";
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f8f8f8;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 10px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    #topnav-right {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <h2><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></h2>
      </a>
      <div id="topnav-right">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Log In</h2>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply the css to class header, rather than the element.

```
header { /*remove the '.'*/
    background-color: red;
}
/* EDIT */
.topnav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;

}
```

Try applying it to your div.

EDIT 2: try adding a height

Comment: doesnt work. if i put it under .topnav a, there will be a color gap between the two floating elements

Comment: Not under .topnav a, just .topnav

Comment: yea, still does not work either even if I put it under .topnav

Comment: why you copied my answer @rileyjsumner?

Comment: @KaushikAndani apologies did not realize you had the same solution. This whole post is 6 of the same answers teaching you how to apply css selectors

Answer (score 1):

Either Change '.header' to 'header' in css, or add `class='header'` to `header` tag.. This should solve your problem.
.header in css refers to a class in html.

**Edit**

Seems like the header div did not have any height. Here is updated code.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #4c8b41;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 87px;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f8f8f8;

    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: black;

}

#topnav-right {
    float: right;    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav header">
            <a href="#"><h2>Home</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></h2></a>
            <div id="topnav-right">
                <a href="#"><h2>Log In</h2></a>
                <a href="#"><h2>Sign Up</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

Comment: i changed it to header but it still does not work somehow

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dot for styles to apply correctly. The dot syntax is for class selection. Header is an HTML element and hence no need of the dot. The reason for header not showing background color is that all elements inside it are set to float. Floating divs do not affect height of the parent. In your case since all elements are floating, parent div height becomes zero and hence you do not see the background color

Comment: do you mind telling me why it won't show up if the child element is set to float? so, how can i have a continuous bakcground color for my header??

Comment: So basically when you set an element to float, it does not affect the height of the parent. Its basically removed from the normal flow of the page. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float. If you want parent to have a height, either set it manually to a certain pixel or remove floating from the elements on the left and just keep the right element as float

Answer (score 1):

```
header { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

if not working than add a id to your header section

```
<body>
    <header id="some_id">
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#"><h2>Home</h2></a>
            <a href="#"><h2><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></h2></a>
            <div id="topnav-right">
                <a href="#"><h2>Log In</h2></a>
                <a href="#"><h2>Sign Up</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

like this 
Than add css

```
#some_id{background-color: red;}
```

or

```
#some_id{background: red;}
```